# JavaFx Hello World Questions

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm new to JavaFx and I'm coming along but have a question.

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent e)
    {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
});
```

Can someone explain why there is a method inside the parentheses and when it is used/is useful. If you don't know how to explain it, can you please just tell me what it is called so I can research it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The button needs an action event when clicked. Clicking that button then does the Hello World message you have there.

Answer (score 0):

The `setOnAction` method takes as its parameter an `EventHandler`.  You could declare a named class that is derived from an EventHandler and pass an instance of it to the setOnAction method, or you can use an Anonymous class.  These are typically used as callback handlers. The definition from the [oracle's java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) is:

> Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They
>   enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They
>   are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them
>   if you need to use a local class only once.

Another useful aspect of anonymous classes is that they can access final variables in it's enclosing scope.  This allows the anonymous inner classes behavior to be affected by the enclosing scope.